# Can we add list of strings to StringArray?

Tags: java

I have String , `String str = "this is a very- good web-page";`

On split of this , based on "`-`"

we get `str[0]`,`str[1]`,and `str[2]`

I want to assign each value of `str[0]` to a string array..

like below

```
String[] array = {"this", "is","a", "very"};
```

is this possible?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: yes. It is possible. Now you can try and come up with your try if you stuck some where.

Comment: so...you hust want to split the result Strings again on " "?

Comment: Why not `{"this","is","a","very"}`

Answer (score 2):

Just split str[0] again on " "

Comment: I dont understand. If you split one string, you get the array of Strings. Then just take the element you're interested and split it again. If str[0] is an array, what are you asking for? how assing array to another array?

Comment: String str = "this is a very- good web-page";
      String[] str1 = str.split("-");
      System.out.println("str1"+str1[0]);
      String strpart = str1[0];
      String[] str2 = strpart.split(" ");
      System.out.println("str2--->"+str2[0]);
      System.out.println("str2--->"+str2[1]);
      System.out.println("str2--->"+str2[2]);
      System.out.println("str2--->"+str2[3]);

Comment: output is : str1this is a very
str2--->this
str2--->is
str2--->a
str2--->very

Answer (score 0):

String str = "this is a very- good web-page";
String[] arr=str.split("-");

Now arr[]={"this is a very","good web","page"};

String[] arr1=arr[0].split(" ");

Now arr1[]={"this","is","a","very"}
I hope you understand now.

Comment: Explaining your code would make your answer more useful than plain code.

Comment: it will give arr1[0]..etc values..but how to assign each single value to String array ...String[] a = {"this","is","a","very"} ??

Answer (score 0):

You start with a string.

```
String str = "this is a very- good web-page";
```

You then split the string.

```
String[] strArray = str.split("-");
```

Here are the contents of `strArray`:

```
{"this is a very", " good web", "page"}
```

Note that, since `strArray` is an array of `String`s, each element (i.e. `strArray[0]`) is a `String`. Now, you split `strArray[0]`.

```
String[] strArray2 = strArray[0].split(" ");
```

Here are the contents of `strArray2`:

```
{"this", "is", "a", "very"}
```

This is the same as if you did the following:

```
String str2 = strArray[0];
String[] strArray2 = str2.split(" ");
```